# Response time in Django app is taking 5 times longer than run time

Tags: python, django, performance

django-debug-toolbar:
[image: django-debug-toolbar]

I have a performance question. Look at the image shared above, the total run time is `231ms`, but response time is `1255ms`. Every request has more than about 800ms duration between response and total run time.
This is resulting in a slow performance of my application.

What is consuming these times?

Comment: Response time includes the time taken to get the result from the server and the propagation delay(network delay in the network).

Comment: That is likely a template render time. Share your template code and rendered data if possible.

Comment: This question is solve.the more time is duration for django-debug-toolbar.Thanks all.